# Python Django - Saving ContentFile to Local Files

Tags: python, django

I'm using ContentFile from Django Python and I have a ContentFile that was previously uploading to a web server.

What I would like to do is also save this ContentFile (it is a PDF) onto my local machine.

```
in : type(file_contents)
out : <class 'django.core.files.base.ContentFile'>

from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
path = default_storage.save('/tmp/file.pdf', file_contents)

in:path
out:u'/tmp/file.pdf'
```

I can't find this file anywhere on my local machine ... I recognize I might be doing something wrong, but any help here would be great. Want to be able to find this PDF on my local machine to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The server can't save files to your local machine. Only your local browser can do that. The only thing the server can do is to present a file for download by the browser.

Comment: Hi Daniel - Sorry, I should clarify, I'm not on a server. I'm using python manage.py shell to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a much simpler answer. What I could do was just open a new file

```
pdf_file = open(LOCAL_PDF_SAVE_LOCATION, "wb")
pdf_file.write(ContentFileContents)
pdf_file.close()
```

This ended up being a much simpler solution, and shows I over thought it a bit too much.